# How to drop the end of variables names in R

Tags: r

Most of my variables (800 variables) end in ".value", I am trying to find a way to rename all of them so as to drop this.  Is this possible in R?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you mean 800 variables in the environment or an object with 800 names?

Comment: ...because if you mean 800 variables in the environment, you should probably be using a `list` instead.

Comment: It is a dataframe with 800 variables.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the suffix `.value` at the end (`$`) of the string in the `names` of the dataset and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
names(df) <- sub("\\.value$", "", names(df))
```

---

If this is not a data.frame and are individual objects created in the global environment, we can get the values in a `list` with `mget`, change the `names` of the `list` using `sub`.

```
 lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "\\.value$"))
 names(lst) <- sub("\\.value$", "", names(lst))
```